# Transpose one column with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I'm trying to learn Pandas and I'm having difficulties to achieve a simple goal.

I have a dataset where I want to transpose the rows of a column in multiple column (check img).
The column "Maximum take-off weight and type of power plant" has 12 different values and the goal is to achive this values become columns filled with "VALUE".
It's also important to keep the other columns, later in the process I will eliminate some of them but I was wondering if it's possible to achieve the goal anyway, I know some of the values in this rows will be lost, like 'COORDINATE'.

I have read the documentation about [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html) and [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html), but I haven't achieved anything. Since I want to keep all the columns and just transform 'Maximum take-off weight and type of power plant' values into columns, filled with values in 'VALUE' I thought I would need to add to 'index' all columns I want to keep.

```
df=df.pivot_table(index=['REF_DATE','GEO','DGUID','Airports','UOM','UOM_ID','SCALAR_FACTOR','SCALAR_ID','VECTOR','COORDINATE','STATUS','SYMBOL','TERMINATED','DECIMALS'],
                  columns='Maximum take-off weight and type of power plant',
                  values ='VALUE')
```

[image]

The output should be something like this:
[image]

Input sample:

```
"REF_DATE","GEO","DGUID","Airports","Maximum take-off weight and type of power plant","UOM","UOM_ID","SCALAR_FACTOR","SCALAR_ID","VECTOR","COORDINATE","VALUE","STATUS","SYMBOL","TERMINATED","DECIMALS"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Maximum take-off weight, 2,000 kilograms and under","Number","223","units ","0","v41840825","1.1.1","3551","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Maximum take-off weight, 2,001 to 4,000 kilograms","Number","223","units ","0","v41840829","1.1.2","4702","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Maximum take-off weight, 4,001 to 5,670 kilograms","Number","223","units ","0","v41840830","1.1.3","4293","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Maximum take-off weight, 5,671 to 9,000 kilograms","Number","223","units ","0","v41840831","1.1.4","1498","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Maximum take-off weight, 9,001 to 18,000 kilograms","Number","223","units ","0","v41840832","1.1.5","1704","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Maximum take-off weight, 18,001 to 35,000 kilograms","Number","223","units ","0","v41840833","1.1.6","1790","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Maximum take-off weight, 35,001 kilograms and over","Number","223","units ","0","v41840834","1.1.7","202","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Power plant, jet engines","Number","223","units ","0","v41840835","1.1.8","475","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Power plant, turbo-propellers","Number","223","units ","0","v41840836","1.1.9","9645","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Power plant, piston engines","Number","223","units ","0","v41840826","1.1.10","6398","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Power plant, helicopters","Number","223","units ","0","v41840827","1.1.11","1203","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Power plant, gliders","Number","223","units ","0","v41840828","1.1.12","19","","","","0"
```

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what your final goal is, your description is a bit confusing. Could you manually construct the output dataframe you're looking for, given your example data, and show us that too?

Comment: Desired output is not clear. Please restate your question with appropriate output.

Comment: Added output example

Comment: Can you post your data in a format that can be worked with (i.e. actual sample data, not an image)?

Comment: @topsail yes i have added a sample of the dataset

Comment: Oh sorry okay great.

Comment: There is a problem here -  VECTOR and "COORDINATE" have different values for every row. How would you want those values to be included in the final results or what is supposed to happen with those columns? It doesn't seem to be a problem of combining "duplicate rows" with the transposition of only VALUE - your desired output isn't making clear what to do entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example in your question, it looks like you only need the `Value` entry in the first row matching each unique `Maximum take-off weight and type of power plant` entry.

Here is a way to do what you've asked (for simplicity, I have shortened the column name to `Max weight and type`, reduced the number of columns and used arbitrary values):

```py
x = df.drop_duplicates('Max weight and type')
y = x[['Max weight and type', 'Value']].set_index('Max weight and type').T.reset_index(drop=True)
y.columns.name=None
cols = list(x.columns)
iWt, iVal = cols.index('Max weight and type'), cols.index('Value')
cols = cols[:iWt] + list(y.columns) + cols[iWt + 1:iVal] + cols[iVal + 1:]
res = x.loc[0,:].drop(columns=['Max weight and type', 'Value']).to_frame().T.reindex(
    columns=cols).assign(**{k:v[0] for k, v in y.to_dict().items()})
```

Sample input:

```
              Airports Max weight and type  Value COORDINATES
0  Total, all airports                  x1     50       1.1.1
1  Total, all airports                  x2    100       1.1.2
2  Total, all airports                  x3    150       1.1.3
3  Total, all airports                  x4    200       1.1.4
4  Total, all airports                  x1     55       1.1.5
5  Total, all airports                  x2    105       1.1.6
6  Total, all airports                  x3    155       1.1.7
```

Output:

```
              Airports  x1   x2   x3   x4 COORDINATES
0  Total, all airports  50  100  150  200       1.1.1
```

Explanation:

- Use [`drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to eliminate all but the first row for each unique value in the `Max weight and type` column
- Create a new DataFrame whose column labels are the unique values from `Max weight and type` and whose only row contains the `Value` entry in the first row of the original dataframe matching each unique `Max weight and type` entry
- Make a column label list which replaces `Max weight and type` with its unique values and eliminates `Value` from the original dataframe's column labels
- Drop the columns to be replaced (`Max weight and type`, `Value`), use `reindex()` to add the `Max weight and type` values as column labels (with NaN values initially), and use `assign()` to overwrite the NaN values in these new columns with the corresponding `Value` entries from the original dataframe.

Comment: @yaviens Do you need additional help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

#pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 10)
#pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) 

df = """
"REF_DATE","GEO","DGUID","Airports","Maximum take-off weight and type of power plant","UOM","UOM_ID","SCALAR_FACTOR","SCALAR_ID","VECTOR","COORDINATE","VALUE","STATUS","SYMBOL","TERMINATED","DECIMALS"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Maximum take-off weight, 2,000 kilograms and under","Number","223","units ","0","v41840825","1.1.1","3551","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Maximum take-off weight, 2,001 to 4,000 kilograms","Number","223","units ","0","v41840829","1.1.2","4702","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Maximum take-off weight, 4,001 to 5,670 kilograms","Number","223","units ","0","v41840830","1.1.3","4293","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Maximum take-off weight, 5,671 to 9,000 kilograms","Number","223","units ","0","v41840831","1.1.4","1498","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Maximum take-off weight, 9,001 to 18,000 kilograms","Number","223","units ","0","v41840832","1.1.5","1704","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Maximum take-off weight, 18,001 to 35,000 kilograms","Number","223","units ","0","v41840833","1.1.6","1790","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Maximum take-off weight, 35,001 kilograms and over","Number","223","units ","0","v41840834","1.1.7","202","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Power plant, jet engines","Number","223","units ","0","v41840835","1.1.8","475","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Power plant, turbo-propellers","Number","223","units ","0","v41840836","1.1.9","9645","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Power plant, piston engines","Number","223","units ","0","v41840826","1.1.10","6398","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Power plant, helicopters","Number","223","units ","0","v41840827","1.1.11","1203","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011124","Total, all airports","Power plant, gliders","Number","223","units ","0","v41840828","1.1.12","19","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011125","Test2","Power plant, piston engines","Number","223","units ","0","v41840826","1.1.10","10000","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011125","Test2","Power plant, helicopters","Number","223","units ","0","v41840827","1.1.11","10001","","","","0"
"1997-01","Canada","2016A000011125","Test2","Power plant, gliders","Number","223","units ","0","v41840828","1.1.12","10002","","","","0"


"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df.strip()), sep=',')



#create a pivot to have one line per DGUID
df1=pd.pivot_table(df, values='VALUE', index='DGUID', columns='Maximum take-off weight and type of power plant').fillna(0).reset_index()

#Merge pivot with intial df
df=df.merge(df1,on='DGUID')
print("----------------------")
print('with All lines:')
print(df)

#if only first line of each DGUID is intereting:
df.drop_duplicates('DGUID',inplace=True)
print("----------------------")
print('Duplicates on DGUID removed:')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
----------------------
with All lines:
   REF_DATE     GEO           DGUID             Airports  ... Power plant, helicopters Power plant, jet engines  Power plant, piston engines Power plant, turbo-propellers
0   1997-01  Canada  2016A000011124  Total, all airports  ...                   1203.0                    475.0                       6398.0                        9645.0
1   1997-01  Canada  2016A000011124  Total, all airports  ...                   1203.0                    475.0                       6398.0                        9645.0
2   1997-01  Canada  2016A000011124  Total, all airports  ...                   1203.0                    475.0                       6398.0                        9645.0
3   1997-01  Canada  2016A000011124  Total, all airports  ...                   1203.0                    475.0                       6398.0                        9645.0
4   1997-01  Canada  2016A000011124  Total, all airports  ...                   1203.0                    475.0                       6398.0                        9645.0
5   1997-01  Canada  2016A000011124  Total, all airports  ...                   1203.0                    475.0                       6398.0                        9645.0
6   1997-01  Canada  2016A000011124  Total, all airports  ...                   1203.0                    475.0                       6398.0                        9645.0
7   1997-01  Canada  2016A000011124  Total, all airports  ...                   1203.0                    475.0                       6398.0                        9645.0
8   1997-01  Canada  2016A000011124  Total, all airports  ...                   1203.0                    475.0                       6398.0                        9645.0
9   1997-01  Canada  2016A000011124  Total, all airports  ...                   1203.0                    475.0                       6398.0                        9645.0
10  1997-01  Canada  2016A000011124  Total, all airports  ...                   1203.0                    475.0                       6398.0                        9645.0
11  1997-01  Canada  2016A000011124  Total, all airports  ...                   1203.0                    475.0                       6398.0                        9645.0
12  1997-01  Canada  2016A000011125                Test2  ...                  10001.0                      0.0                      10000.0                           0.0
13  1997-01  Canada  2016A000011125                Test2  ...                  10001.0                      0.0                      10000.0                           0.0
14  1997-01  Canada  2016A000011125                Test2  ...                  10001.0                      0.0                      10000.0                           0.0

[15 rows x 28 columns]
----------------------
Duplicates on DGUID removed:
   REF_DATE     GEO           DGUID             Airports  ... Power plant, helicopters Power plant, jet engines  Power plant, piston engines Power plant, turbo-propellers
0   1997-01  Canada  2016A000011124  Total, all airports  ...                   1203.0                    475.0                       6398.0                        9645.0
12  1997-01  Canada  2016A000011125                Test2  ...                  10001.0                      0.0                      10000.0                           0.0

[2 rows x 28 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to keep the original df and just add some columns with names and values from two different existing columns you can try this with remark that the original values populate just the first row of new columns. Regards...

```py
import pandas as pd

#   sample dictionary
data = {'A': [11,47,33],
        'B': ['max_x','max_y','max_z'],
        'C': [77,56,99]
        }
#   sample df
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])

#   Create two lists of columns containing names and values for new columns
b_list = list(df['B'])
c_list = list(df['C'])

# To keep the whole df as it is and add some new columns get the length of the series in the column (number of rows)
list_length = len(b_list)

#   for new column create list populated with zeros so you would have a list of the size of the df series
i = 0
new_col_list = []
for i in range(list_length):
    new_col_list.append(0)

#   insert columns
for i in range(list_length):
    # put the value from your original df in the first element of the new_col_list, all others will be zeros
    new_col_list[0] = c_list[i]     
    # create and execute the command to insert a new column at position where you want (the end in this case)
    cmd = 'df.insert(' + str(len(b_list)  + i) + ', "' + str(b_list[i]) + '", ' + str(new_col_list) +', True)'
    exec(cmd)
    i += 1
print(df)
#
#   Original df
#
#           A      B   C
#       0  11  max_x  77
#       1  47  max_y  56
#       2  33  max_z  99
#
#
#   Insert commands generated in this script are:
#
#   df.insert(3, "max_x", [77, 0, 0], True)
#   df.insert(4, "max_y", [56, 0, 0], True)
#   df.insert(5, "max_z", [99, 0, 0], True)
#
#   ---------------------------------------------
#   R e s u l t :
#
#           A      B   C  max_x  max_y  max_z
#       0  11  max_x  77     77     56     99
#       1  47  max_y  56      0      0      0
#       2  33  max_z  99      0      0      0
```